# Generate ISO 8601 Duration String from Two Date Objects

Tags: javascript, datetime

I've written a function which should generate an ISO 8601 duration string, given two Dates as input.

````js
import {
  differenceInYears,
  differenceInMonths,
  differenceInWeeks,
  differenceInDays,
  getDaysInYear,
  eachYearOfInterval,
} from 'date-fns/esm'; // v2.11.0

/**
 * Given a start Date and an end Date, returns an ISO 8601 duration string
 * Only supports Year, Month, Week, and Day. Does not support Hour or smaller.
 * @param  {Date} start
 * @param  {Date} end
 * @return {string} ISO 8601 Duration
 * @example
 * ```js
 * toISODurationString(new Date('2020'), new Date('2021'));
 * // => PY1
 * ```
 */
export function toISODurationString(start, end) {
  const differenceInDaysOverYears =
    eachYearOfInterval({ start, end })
      .map(getDaysInYear)
      .map(days => days % 365)
      .reduce(add) - 365;

  const Y = differenceInYears(end, start);
  const M = differenceInMonths(end, start) - 12;
  const W = differenceInWeeks(end, start) - 52;
  const D = differenceInDays(end, start) - (365 + differenceInDaysOverYears);

  return Object.entries({ Y, M, W, D })
    .reduce((s, [c, v]) => `${s}${v !== 0 ? c + v : ''}`, 'P');
}
````

I'm concerned about the `differenceInDaysOverYears` part. Is this code reliable? Specifically, will it robustly handle any Date you give it?

Comment: What will happen in `days % 365` if a year has `366` days?

Comment: `differenceInDaysOverYears` will increment by 1 for each such year in the interval. `const add = (x, y) => x + y`

Comment: Will it be (366 % 365) - 365 == -364 ?

Comment: `const D = differenceInDays(end, start) - (365 + differenceInDaysOverYears);` so we have the total difference in days, say for a 1 year interval of 366 days === 366, minus the typical year, minus the delta, equals 0